# Method prototype in ES6

Tags: javascript

I want to make write this using ES6, however I am stuck and need your help.
When I use ES6 do declare my method, the method prototype gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'move' of undefined  at planesJS.js:238

```
let SI = {};
//some SI.Properties that i need...

// SI.SpaceShip = function (options) { // works fine
SI.SpaceShip = (options) => { // gives error
let defaultOptions = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    img: null,
    imgX: 0, 
}
for (let key in defaultOptions) {
    if(options.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        this[key] = options[key];
    }
    else {
        this[key] = defaultOptions[key];
    }
}
}
```

This is the Prototype:

```
SI.SpaceShip.prototype.move = function (deltaX, deltaY) {
    this.x += deltaX;
    if(this.x <= 0) {
        this.x = 0;
    }
    else if(this.x >= SI.Sizes.width - this.width) {
        this.x = SI.Sizes.width - this.width;
    }

    this.y += deltaY;
    if(this.y <= 0) {
        this.y = 0;
    }
    else if(this.y >= SI.Sizes.height - this.height) {
        this.x = SI.Sizes.height - this.height;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to move to ES6, why not use the class syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow function does not have prototype and cannot be used as an object constructor. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> An arrow function expression [...] does not have its own this,
>   arguments, super, or **new.target**. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions, and **they cannot be used as constructors**.

You can fix it like that

```
SI.SpaceShip = function (options) { ...
```